# how could I import project from eclipse to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

as you can see, this error comes from AndroidManifest.xml, it occurs in android studio, I looked up a lot information, and don't know how it causes, I appreciate you if you could give me a hand.

the other thing I want to add, the activity showed illeagal in this file.

Answer (score 2):

It got simpler in newer versions of android studio.

1. Just close your current project by File-> Close Project. After doing this the Screen shot shown/(similar to) below will appear.

[image]

2. Select the rounded circle highlighted option. Which says You can import projects from **Eclipse ADT**.
3. After that select your project from directory and wait untill the build finishes.

Comment: I did as you said,but there were always some errors in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: do one thing. make a New Folder outside **your workspace** just paste your project to the New Folder. And then try to import project from that New Folder only following above method.

Comment: 1. Select element in xml that displays error.
   2.Press alt + enter on the drawable item which calls error (for example: "@drawable/example").
   3.And select "Uninject language/reference"  this answer works for me,thank you very much

Comment: I am glad it helped. :)